# How to calculate the speedup of a GPU program?

Tags: performance, cuda, gpgpu, metrics

**Motivation:** I have been tasked with measuring the [Karp-Flatt metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karp%E2%80%93Flatt_metric) and [parallel efficiency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_efficiency) of my CUDA C code, which requires computation of speedup. In particular, I need to plot all these metrics as a function of the number of processors *`p`*.

**Definition:** [Speedup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speedup) refers to how much a parallel algorithm is faster than a corresponding sequential algorithm, and is defined as:

[image]

**Issue:** I have implemented my algorithm in **CUDA C**, and have timed it to get *`Tp`*. However, there remains some issues in determining *`Sp`*:

- How to observe *`T1`* without completely rewriting my code from scratch?

  - Can I execute CUDA code in serial???
- What is *`p`* when I run different kernels with different numbers of threads?

  - Does it refer to no. of threads or no. of processors used throughout runtime?
  - Since both of these quantities will also vary throughout runtime, is it the maximum or the average used?
  - How do I even restrict my code to run on a subset of processors or with fewer threads!?

Many thanks.

Comment: If I remember correctly (coming from an OpenCL background), if you set the number of kernels to one, wouldn't that be the same as running the program in serial?

Comment: @ChaseWalden You still use several cores on the GPU assuming block dim > 1, the only way is to use one kernel of size one thread, but this is sort of baseless as GPU and CPU is too diverse. It would make more sense to implement a CPU bound algorithm and compare.

Comment: @ks6g10 so if I am understanding you correctly, you want to calculate the speedup from a program run in serial on the CPU to the program run on multiple kernels on the GPU?

Comment: @ChaseWalden For me that seems to be the domain you want to try, as if if the CPU is faster to do it by a notable amount (e.g. 2x), why then do it on the GPU? At least that is what I do for my research.

Comment: @ks6g10 Im not fully sure what you are wanting to do.

Comment: @ChaseWalden You said he should just run one kernel, I specified it should be one kernel of one thread if he would do that. But then I suggested him that he should do a CPU bound algorithm instead to measure performance du to the platforms being so different.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To get a reasonable measure of speedup, you need *the actual sequential program*.  If you don't have one, you need to write the best sequential version you can, because comparing a highly tuned parallel code to a junk serial implementation is unreasonable.

Nor can you reasonably compare a 1-processor version of your parallel program to the N-processor version to get a true measure of speedup.   Such a comparison tells you speedup from going from P=1 to P=N for the same program, but the point of the speedup curves is to show why building a parallel program (which is usually harder amd requires more complicated hardware [GPU] and tools [OpenCL]) makes sense compared to coding the best sequential version using more widely available hardware and tools.

In other words, no cheating.

Comment: Good answer, but do you think that say, ranking the best CPU vs the best GPU makes sense? Or should it be so that you would also consider the hardware cost?

Comment: You say "such a comparison tells you speedup from going from P=1 to P=N for the same program" as if this is missing the main point of computing speedup - isn't this the *entire* point of measuring speedup?

Comment: Moreover, with respect to GPGPU, does the *`p`* used in the definition of speedup refer to no. of threads or no. of processors? Indeed, since both of these quantities will also vary throughout runtime, is it the maximum or the average used?

Comment: @MiloChen I think he is suggesting that you have the capability of running multi threaded code which in most cases would be beneficial(and could be faster than the GPU), and being lazy and not evaluating the possibility is wrong.

Comment: @ksg6g10:  Well, a "multithreaded" code is another kind of parallel program.   To get a true measure of parallel speedup *over a sequential program*, he has to compare to a sequential  program.  He can do another comparision to a multithreaded, non-GPU application to indicate payoff of going that way.  But ultimately speedup is judged against what is straightforward to write with standard resources and effort, against what you can get with the extra resources and effort.   If it is trivial to code a multithreaded app (not always so for C and C++), then that might make in intersting comparison.

Comment: This answer is completely correct in that you cannot simply run your parallel algorithm on one thread. You must write an optimized serial algorithm and compare against that.

Answer (score 0):

When measuring speedup you must in most cases completely write both the serial and the parallel algorithms from scratch. There is no particular reason that the best parallel algorithm with P=1 has anything in common with the optimal serial algorithm. In most cases the parallel algorithm will have to do lots of extra work and is quite inefficient compared to an optimal serial algorithm.